# How can i execute angular script after onclick event

Tags: angularjs

Here is my html code:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
      <p id="druzyny"></p>
    </div>
```

and then in angular script:

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        document.getElementById("search1").onclick = app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        var place = document.getElementById("place").value;
        var sel1 = document.getElementById("sel1").value;
        var sel2 = document.getElementById("sel2").value;
        var req = {
          method: 'post', 
          url: 'findTournament',
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
          }, 
          data: {place: 'test'} 
        };

        $http(req).then(function(response){
      });
      });
```

I`ve got button id="search1" and i want that angular execute only when i click this button, no automatically when page is reload, is it possible?
Thanks for answears

Comment: Why you want to execute Angular only when you click on a button? Seems tad weird

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: i need to make request to server but with data from fields

Comment: Bobbyrogers  ng-click works ng-click="expression" so can i put there whole my angular script? Sorry probably some of my questions are stupid but i am new in programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl as customers">
  <input data-ng-model="customers.place">
  <input data-ng-model="customers.sel1">
  <input data-ng-model="customers.sel2">
  <button data-ng-click="customers.init()"></button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular
   .module('myApp')
   .controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, customersService){
      var vm = this;
      vm.init = function(){
        customersService.findTournament({place: vm.place, sel1: vm.sel1, sel2: vm.sel2})
           .then(function(res){});
      };

    });

angular
   .module('myApp')
   .service('customersService', function($http){
      return {
         findTournament: findTournament
      };

      function findTournament(data){
         return $http.post('findTournament', data);
      }
   });
```